# Ruby on Rails, Apache, Passenger error 500 when try to upload images in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, dragonfly-gem

I have an ubuntu server with apache (2.4.7) + passenger (5.0.0.beta2) + rails (4.2.0) + dragonfly (1.0.7)

The site is running OK, but when I upload images its when the server sends a 500 error. Sometimes allows me to upload one image and the second one sends a 500, sometimes the error appears when I try to upload the third image. (the size of the images are around the 100KB and the 700KB)

In the production.log there is no error. But in the apache error.log I have a lot of information but nothing that can help me, maybe one of you could understand the log:

```
[ pid=25856, timestamp=1422360930 ] Process aborted! signo=SIGSEGV(11), reason=SEGV_MAPERR, si_addr=0x10, randomSeed=1422360655
[ pid=25856 ] Crash log dumped to /var/tmp/passenger-crash-log.1422360930
[ pid=25856 ] Date, uname and ulimits:
Tue Jan 27 07:15:30 EST 2015
Linux 3.13.0-042stab094.8 #1 SMP Tue Dec 16 20:36:56 MSK 2014 x86_64 x86_64
time(seconds)        unlimited
file(blocks)         unlimited
data(kbytes)         unlimited
stack(kbytes)        10240
coredump(blocks)     0
memory(kbytes)       unlimited
locked memory(kbytes) 64
process              1029939
nofiles              8192
vmemory(kbytes)      unlimited
locks                unlimited
[ pid=25856 ] Phusion Passenger version: 5.0.0.beta2
[ pid=25856 ] libc backtrace available!
--------------------------------------
[ pid=25856 ] Backtrace with 23 frames:
Using backtrace sanitizer.
PassengerAgent server[0x4d08d3]
PassengerAgent server[0x4d0185]
PassengerAgent server[0x4d1483]
PassengerAgent server[0x4d213d]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(?? at ??:0; +0x10340) [0x7fb9f915c340]
PassengerAgent server[0x5013de]
PassengerAgent server[0x5050b9]
PassengerAgent server[0x6858fb]
PassengerAgent server[0x6878db]
PassengerAgent server[0x539c40]
PassengerAgent server[0x68111e]
PassengerAgent server[0x681ff8]
PassengerAgent server[0x539bc2]
PassengerAgent server[0x5c68c9]
PassengerAgent server[0x5c16ed]
PassengerAgent server[0x5bc69a]
PassengerAgent server[0x64f027]
PassengerAgent server[0x4cec46]
PassengerAgent server[0x4ce831]
PassengerAgent server[0x4ce01c]
PassengerAgent server[0x6226b9]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(?? at ??:0; +0x8182) [0x7fb9f9154182]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(?? at ??:0; clone+0x6d) [0x7fb9f845900d]
--------------------------------------
[ pid=25856 ] Dumping additional diagnostical information...
--------------------------------------
### Backtraces
Thread 'Main thread' (0x7fb9f99ef7c0, LWP 25856):
     in 'void waitForExitEvent()' (Main.cpp:778)
     in 'void mainLoop()' (Main.cpp:671)
     in 'int runServer()' (Main.cpp:893)

Thread 'Pool analytics collector' (0x7fb9f99ed700, LWP 25856):
     in 'static void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Pool::collectAnalytics(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::PoolPtr)' (Pool.h:829)

     Thread 'Pool garbage collector' (0x7fb9f99ac700, LWP 25856):
     in 'static void
Passenger::ApplicationPool2::Pool::garbageCollect(Passenger::ApplicationPool2::PoolPtr)' (Pool.h:684)

Thread 'Main event loop: thread 1' (0x7fb9f2a6c700, LWP 25856):
 (empty)
```

And the files goes on....

Also, at the end of error.log I see a:

```
 No locals.[ 2015-01-27 07:15:34.0702 12438/7f20597d2700 agents/Watchdog/AgentWatcher.cpp:96 ]: Phusion Passenger helper agent (pid=25856) crashed with signal SIGSEGV, restarting it...

[Tue Jan 27 07:15:34.077773 2015] [core:error] [pid 12483:tid 140022065903360]  [client 200.71.213.222:50038] End of script output before headers: profiles, referer: http://www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com/profiles/username-something/avatar/edit
[ 2015-01-27 07:15:34.0849 26021/7f56396e37c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:881 ]: Starting PassengerAgent server...
[ 2015-01-27 07:15:34.0852 26021/7f56396e37c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:232 ]: PassengerAgent server running in multi-application mode.
[ 2015-01-27 07:15:34.0965 26021/7f56396e37c0 agents/HelperAgent/Main.cpp:635 ]: PassengerAgent server online, PID 26021
App 26054 stdout: 
App 26071 stdout:
```

How can I try to resolve this issue? Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

Well, right now I downgrade to passenger 4.0.58 and reload/restart everything. I made a couple of test uploading files in different sections of the site, and everything is responding OK. For now this is a good solution.